# Best Practices for mutable | immutable objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Should we use the first way or second way to update the settings object in the state? Which one is the best practice for the mutable | immutable concept?

```
state = {
  settings: {
    at: [],
    // other keys
  }
}


addHour = () => {
    const { settings } = this.state;

    const time = moment();
    time.set({ minutes: 0, seconds: 0 });

    // First Way
    settings.at.push(time);
    this.setState({ settings });

    // Second Way
    const new_settings = {
        ...settings
        at: [...settings.at, time]
    }
    this.setState({ settings: new_settings });
};
```

Comment: the first one is probably wrong, you are not supposed to mutate the state. (https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/)

Comment: second way, if the references are the same a re-render is not guaranteed.

Comment: Second way is the right way

Comment: there is deep copy and shallow copy for the composite datatypes.
In your first way your ae doing it as shallow copy and in second as deep copy.
Both of them does copy but in different ways depends whether you want to refer the original object or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code

```
const { settings } = this.state;
```

this  isn't making any copy it's just an reference and when you do `settings.at.push(time);` you're actually mutating original object

```js
let state = {
  settings: [1,2,3]
}
let {settings} = state
settings.push(4)

console.log(settings)
console.log(state)
```

If your settings array is always one level deep you can use `spread operator` otherwise you can use `JOSN.parse(JOSN.stringify())` to create a deep clone

```js
let state = {
  settings: [1, 2, 3]
}
let settings = [...state.settings]
settings.push(4)

console.log(settings)
console.log(state)
```

Comment: @Kevin.a it's considered as good practice to answer in well detailed manner, so it will help future readers too. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1):

In the first way you're still mutating the original state object. Its called a reference to the original object. The second way makes a clone of the state. Its 2 different objects.

Answer (score 0):

In the first way you are referencing to the actual state, mutating it.

In the second way you are not mutating the state, be aware of one thing anyway:

that type of assignment is not thread safe, look at the following example:

```
const { settings } = this.state;

const time = moment();
time.set({ minutes: 0, seconds: 0 });

// If at this execution point another procedure changes the state (e.g. setting another key in the state object)
const new_settings = {
    ...settings
    at: [...settings.at, time]
};
// You are actually setting an "old" state for some keys
this.setState({ settings: new_settings });
```

I would go for the following:

```
this.setState(oldSettings => {
    const newSettings = {...oldSettings};
    //modify the copy newSettings
    return newSettings;
});
```

N.B. If the state is complex you have to deep clone it!